# Same folder with different exclude patterns in ST2 project

Tags: project, sublimetext2

I have a project where everything is sitting in the same folder, called `/development` (`/` is project root). Some of the files are source code, some are shellscripts, some are gnuplot scripts etc. I'd rather not move the files around, since many of them depend on their relative paths to each other, but it would be nice to have a little more structure in the file view in Sublime Text 2.

To accomplish this, I tried to create several project folders with different exclude patterns, like this (in the project file):

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "development",
            "name": "Fortran",
            "file_exclude_patterns": [".fuse*", "*.png", "*.md", "*.gp", "*.sh"],
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["data", "outdata", "plots"]
        },
        {
            "path": "development",
            "name": "Shell scripts",
            "file_exclude_patterns": [".fuse*", "*.png", "*.md", "*.gp", "*.f"],
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["data", "outdata", "plots"]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see, the two entries differ only in `name` and in the last item of `file_exclude_patterns`.

I expected ST2 to show me two folders, one called `Fortran` and one called `Shell scripts`, both showing contents from the same folder on the file system, but with different filters. But only the first one shows up. With the file as above, I only see `Fortran` - if I interchange the items, I only see `Shell scripts`.

I assume this is because the folders have the same `path`, but is there a way around this (that doesn't involve actually moving any files on the file system)?

Comment: What about creating two symlinks to that folder. You could then have different "paths" even though they reference the same thing. I haven't tried it, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: @skuroda: Yeah, that could work. Ideally I'd like to do it without altering the file system alltogether (now I still have to find somewhere out-of-sight to place the symlinks...) but it's better than nothing. Is what I really want impossible - in other words, is the interpretation of "folders" in this sense mapped 1:1 with paths in the implementation?

Comment: Based on what you said, I would say yes. But honestly, I'm not 100% sure. You could ask on the ST forums, though I don't know if anyone else would have better insight.